# technologies to make a website

Tags: html, sql, database, web

I wonder what technologies I need to know to make a simple website that will support a database.

I have already made a simple CRUD web site using Spring(Spring MVC , Spring Data JPA),Java of course and thymeleaf as a template resolver.

So what are my other options? Which ways of building a website are better and why?

EDIT: I'm NOT asking what technologies I need to know to build a Database for the website.I'm asking what ways of building the website I have.For example I can use Java + Spring MVC + Sping Data Jpa + MySQL + Thymeleaf, or PHP + SQlite + Angular , etc...

Comment: Simple answer would be SQL.

Comment: I'm NOT asking what technologies I need to know to build a Database for the website.I'm asking what ways of building the website I have.For example I can use Java + Spring MVC + Sping Data Jpa + MySQL + Thymeleaf, or PHP + SQlite + Angular etc...

Comment: Your first line says "I wonder what technologies I need to know". And now you are saying I am not asking ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A popular way of creating a website with a functional database is to use SQlite3 or MySQL. Depending on your preference, as SQlite3 stores your database as files and MySQL works through a server to store info. Both of these can be implemented into your website using a server-side language such as PHP or Python.

Although both are efficient, I've used SQlite3 in the past for a simple website. Since it is stored within a file system, the response times are pretty fast. 
https://www.sqlite.org/aff_short.html

I'm sure you know that you would have to learn SQL for each software in order to create the database, and retrieve it once you are done.

Comment: Ok, well then based on your edit, I'm saying you can use PHP/Python+ SQL + SQlite3  or you can use a similar combination with MySQL instead. I know you can use Java as well, but I've never attempted this.